# Error 401 when doing POST with Angular 2

Tags: angular

I am trying to make a `post`, but I am not able to send the data to the `provider`.

On the page where I receive the information I can display them correctly, but when I try to send them to the provider they go as `undefined` or an empty result.

It also displays the errors: **OPTIONS http: //my.url/api/todo 401 (Unauthorized)** and **Uncaught (in promise): Response with status: 0 for URL: null**

**modal.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { ReviewService } from '../../providers/review-service';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-modal',
  templateUrl: 'modal.html'
})
export class ModalPage {

  private url: string = "http://my.url";
  pessoa = [];

  constructor(private _service: ReviewService) { }

  peopleForm() {
    console.log(this.pessoa); // Aqui eu consigo pegar as informações
    this._service.novo(this.pessoa).then(res => {
      console.log("Enviou para o provider");
    })
  }
}
```

**review-service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

@Injectable()
export class ReviewService {

  private url = 'http://my.url/post';
  private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
    console.error('An error occurred', error);
    return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
  }
  private headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});

  constructor(public http: Http) { }

  novo(pessoa: Array<string>) {
    console.log("Exibir o que recebeu: " + pessoa); // Aqui me retorna undefined ou vazio
    return this.http
      .post(this.url, JSON.stringify(pessoa), {headers: this.headers})
      .toPromise()
      .then(res => res.json().data)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

}
```

Comment: Looks like you need to track down that authorization problem, it seems your code isn't allowed to access that todo service for one reason or another (and that can be a few things).  Angular 2 frustratingly shows "Uncaught error in Promise" for (as far as I can see) everything, sort of like "Error in Car Motion" regardless of whether it's a flat tire, empty gas tank, or collision with a tree. So I wouldn't focus on that as the root problem.

Comment: See the network logs, it seems that cross domain access has not been setup correctly on the server side. The call to OPTIONS should succeed.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a **service** *to authenticate* like this.

```
import { CanActivate, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

/**
* Class that deals with redirect to login if user tries to
* access any route without being logged in.
**/
@Injectable()
export class CanActivateAuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  /**
  * Overrides abstract methods that grants the permison to access a url
  * if token is stored in Angular Local Storage.
  **/
  canActivate(): boolean {
    let currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
    if (currentUser) {
      return true;
    } else {
      this.router.navigate(['/login/login']);
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

In each **routing.module** use it:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { CanActivateAuthGuard } from '../shared/auth/auth.service';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    canActivate: [CanActivateAuthGuard],
    data: {
      title: 'General User'
    },
    children: [
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class GeneralRoutingModule {}
```